# Customized button using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a button and tested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bqpBR/2/) is working.
But in my code, I tried a few modifications but nothing works.
The image is shown below and can see that button is not shown properly.

My full code is shown below, not sure what is wrong? What could be the problem, tested on `JSFiddle` works, but doesn't work at my `webpage`?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<style type="text/css">
#background {background: url(main_background.jpg);}


<!-- Top menu css -->
hr {
    border:none;
    border-top:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    height:1px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    }

#maintopmenucontainer{
    height:24px;
    background:#000;
    display:block;
    padding:45px 0 0 15px;
    }

#maintopmenu{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    height:24px;
    font-size:11px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial,Verdana,Helvitica,sans-serif;
    }

#maintopmenu ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:auto;
    }

#maintopmenu ul li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0 1px 0 0;
    }

#maintopmenu ul li a{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:5px 20px 0 20px;
    height:19px;
    background:transparent url(maintopmenu_bg-OFF.gif) no-repeat top left;
    }

#maintopmenu ul li a:hover{
    color:#fff;
    background:transparent url(maintopmenu_bg-OVER.gif) no-repeat top right;
    }

#maintopmenu ul li a.current,#foxmenu ul li a.current:hover{
    color:#000;
    background:#fff;
    }
<!-- Top menu css -->

<!-- Drop Down Menu -->
fieldset {
      border: 0;
    }
    label {
      display: block;
      margin: 30px 0 0 0;

    }
    select {
      width: 150px;

    }
    .overflow {
      height: 200px;
    }
<!-- Drop Down Menu -->

.button {
position: absolute;
border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;
background: #65a9d7;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3e779d),
    to(#65a9d7) );
padding: 5px 10px;
border-radius: 4px;
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0 1px 0;
text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4) 0 1px 0;
color: white;
font-size: 19px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: Segoe;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
display: block;
width: 200px;
text-align: center; 
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<hr />
<div id="maintopmenucontainer">
  <div id="maintopmenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#Landed" class="current"><span>Landed</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#Landed"><span>Apartment</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#Condominium"><span>Condominium</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#Commecial"><span>Commecial</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#Farm"><span>Farm</span></a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="background">
<form name="Landed"  id="Landed" method="post" >

<br /><br /><br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name="divstate" id="divstate" >
      <optgroup label="Divisions" selected="selected">
      <option>Yangon</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>          
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="States">
      <option>9</option>
      <option>10</option>
      <option>11</option>
      <option>12</option>
      </optgroup>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<select name="township" id="township" >      
      <option>Yangon</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      </optgroup>
</select>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input maxlength="100" type="text" name="min_price" id="min_price" placeholder="Minimum price"/>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input maxlength="100" type="text" name="max_price" id="max_price" placeholder="Maximum price"/>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a class="button" onclick="searchButtonAction()" id="search" href="#"><span>Search</span></a>
<br /><br /><br />
</form>
</div>

</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu').dropit();
});
$('#max_price-error').css('display', 'block');
$('#max_price-error').html('Please enter to rent or to sell');
</script>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: you have a <span></span> around your Search element, so maybe .button span {} is the element you want to style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3e779d),
    to(#65a9d7) );
background: linear-gradient(#3e779d, #65a9d7 );
```

You have only -webkit- gradient. Add normal one.

Comment: I would also link to [this tool](http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor) which is for creating cross browser CSS ;)

Comment: Nice the gradient tools is really useful.